# Expected result doesn't match the actual result REST-assured

Tags: java, unit-testing, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I'm testing **changePassword()** method. I'm checking by giving a wrong password firstly, then giving parameters correctly on the second part. However, for the wrong password, it's giving me error for the body(). If I **log().body()** it doesn't print out anything, but the status code matches. If I do **body("errors[0]",equalTo("Wrong password"))** it shows me error for this line saying "*Expected response body to be verified as `JSON`, `HTML` or `XML` but no `content-type` was defined in the response.*"

```
 given().
            contentType("application/json").
            header("ID", "2501").
            param("newPass", "pass2017").
            param("oldPass", "pass2015"). // wrong password
            when().
            put("/v1/password").
            then().
            statusCode(400).
            //log().body();
            body("errors[0]",equalTo("Wrong password"));
```

Also for correct parameters, it says `Expected status code <200> doesn't match actual status code <400>.` I don't know what parameters I could have given wrong, it seems everything is OK. Can anyone explain me what could be wrong in these pieces of code?

```
 given().
            contentType("application/json").
            header("ID", "2501").
            param("newPass", "pass2017").
            param("oldPass", "pass2016").
            when().
            put("/v1/password").
            then().
            statusCode(200).
            //log().body();
            body("content.response", equalTo(true)) ;
```

Thanks!

UPDATE:
I checked this method on Swagger, it works fine.

Comment: you wrote the code, you wrote it's configuration, you run the server, ...

Comment: @Stultuske I don't get you

Comment: kenkulan: I mean there's a lot more information you could/should provide. we don't know what is configured. 400 means "Bad request", so it looks like what you send as request doesn't match what is expected on the back-end